# Flutter :How to build a infinite list using future builder that display n-record at a time

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a list view in flutter that load data base on index and record per page

I am able to display a fix number of record but need some help how get and display the next set of record and so on

Here is my code snippet

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        searchBoxWidget(),
        Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getRecordToDisplay(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('You have some error : ');
                  } else if (snapshot.data != null) {
                    return buildListView(snapshot);
                  } else {
                    return Text('You have some error : ');
                  }
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }


void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {}
    });
  }




 Future<Jobs> getRecordToDisplay() async {
    return await getJobs(startPage, recordPerFetch);
  }


 ListView buildListView(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.hits.length,
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => DetailPage(
                        lobId: snapshot.data.hits[index].lobId,
                        atsReference: snapshot.data.hits[index].atsReference),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),

                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Flexible(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data.hits[index].title,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff2175D9),
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text(
                      snapshot.data.hits[index].jobLocation.city +
                          " , " +
                          snapshot
                              .data.hits[index].jobLocation.stateAbbreviation,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff0f1941),
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data.hits[index].salary.salaryString,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff0f1941),
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data.hits[index].createdDate,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff0f1941),
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8.0,
                    ),
                    Divider(color: Colors.brown),
                  ],
                ),
              ));
        });
  }
```

So, it loads the first  with n record  but I don't know how to  load the next set of pages when you reach the bottom of the current record with a future builder.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you provide the buildListView Widget?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla -- added the widget .. Thanks for your help

Comment: what you're looking for is a pagination of items? Like, showing 20 items, then adding extra 20 and so on?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla  Yes.. So, the first time (index =0) show the first 50 record. The user then scroll ,when they reach the end set index =1 and get next 50 record and so on.. The user should be able to scroll in both direction

Comment: You can follow this guide to achieve the lazy loading pagination: https://medium.com/@KarthikPonnam/flutter-loadmore-in-listview-23820612907d

Comment: Thanks .. I see that but how do you do it with a future builder

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting an infinite list to be displayed, won't [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) be better? Do you have a particular use case for the need to use FutureBuilder specifically? Here's a simple demo that uses Firestore to provide data, and `ListView.builder` with pagination.

This sample implements snippets from Firebase official doc for [Firestore pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query).

There are two ways to load the data on the view in this demo.

- Refresh the entire `ListView` using
  [`RefreshIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html)
- Scroll down to hit the bottom of the list to load up the next documents in the `ListView`.
  [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html)
  is used to determine if the user has hit the bottom part of the list.

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'DocObj.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDocuments();
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        if (scrollController.position.pixels == 0)
          print('ListView scroll at top');
        else {
          print('ListView scroll at bottom');
          getDocumentsNext(); // Load next documents
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: listDocument.length != 0
            ? RefreshIndicator(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: scrollController,
                  itemCount: listDocument.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('${listDocument[index].documentName}'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                onRefresh: getDocuments, // Refresh entire list
              )
            : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<DocObj> listDocument;
  QuerySnapshot collectionState;
  // Fetch first 15 documents
  Future<void> getDocuments() async {
    listDocument = List();
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('sample_pagination')
        .orderBy("name")
        .limit(15);
    print('getDocuments');
    fetchDocuments(collection);
  }

  // Fetch next 5 documents starting from the last document fetched earlier
  Future<void> getDocumentsNext() async {
    // Get the last visible document
    var lastVisible = collectionState.docs[collectionState.docs.length-1];
    print('listDocument legnth: ${collectionState.size} last: $lastVisible');

    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('sample_pagination')
        .orderBy("name").startAfterDocument(lastVisible).limit(5);

    fetchDocuments(collection);
  }

  fetchDocuments(Query collection){
    collection.get().then((value) {
      collectionState = value; // store collection state to set where to start next
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        print('getDocuments ${element.data()}');
        setState(() {
          listDocument.add(DocObj(DocObj.setDocDetails(element.data())));
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

To parse the data inside the document, you can create a model for your object.

```dart
class DocObj {
  var documentName;

  DocObj(DocObj doc) {
    this.documentName = doc.getDocName();
  }

  dynamic getDocName() => documentName;

  DocObj.setDocDetails(Map<dynamic, dynamic> doc)
      : documentName = doc['name'];
}
```

The sample handles this data from Firestore.

[image: firestore dashboard]

Here's how the app looks when running.

[image: demo]